# How to iterate through two lists at one time and count results if they match Python

Tags: python, bayesian

I am trying to write a function based on Bayes theorem that counts a probability of Rainy day if the game has not been played. The background is there is a list of weathers and a list of info whether the game has been played.

For now I am trying to write a function that will return a probability of Rain in a universe where the game has not been played.

Inputs:

```
weather = string ->('Sunny'/Overcast'/'Rainy')
played = boolean ->('Yes'/'No')
```

```
weather_data= ['Sunny','Overcast','Rainy','Sunny','Sunny','Overcast','Rainy','Rainy','Sunny',
'Rainy','Sunny','Overcast','Overcast','Rainy']
play_data   =['No','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No']
```

```
def likelihood(weather, played, weather_data, play_data):
    yes = 0    
    for i in weather_data:
        weather_data[i] == "Rainy" and play_data[i] == "No" 
        yes+1
    
    no = play_data.count("No")
    return float(yes/no)
```

Basically the idea is to add to yes if there is a match between indices that says Rainy in the weather_data and No in the play_data

Comment: One liner:  `yes = sum( w==p for w,p in zip(weather_data,play_data))`.

Comment: The thing is w cannot equal p for them to be counted. Its only when w == "Rainy" and p== "No"

Comment: yes = sum( w=="Rainy" and p=="No" for w,p in zip(weather_data,play_data))

Comment: Duh, I knew that.  My mistake.  I'm glad you substituted the correct comparison.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.